# RXJS6 Websocket Subject Subscription issue with Redux Observables

Tags: websocket, rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs6

I am trying to have on-demand wensocket connection in my React-Redux application. RxJS gives webscoketSubject for managing webscokets. On reception of action, I want to start a connection using webscoketSubject, for subsequent start webscokets request, I would reuse the socket, if already a connection is established. But when I am doing it, a new subscription is getting created in webscoketSubject reference I am holding in memory and cause of that whenever I receive message from Server, I am getting duplicate actions.

Here is the snippet of the code.

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { delay, mapTo, switchMap, mergeMap, map, skipUntil, skipWhile, takeUntil, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, DataEvent, WebSocket, of } from 'rxjs';
import { WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

let socket;

const getWebSocket = () => {
    console.log("socket", socket);
    if(socket) {
        console.log(socket.closed);
    }
    if(!socket) {
        console.log("creating new socket");
        socket = new WebSocketSubject("ws://localhost:9091/web-socket");
    }
    return socket;
}

//maps a websocket recieved message to redux store types
const websocketMsgMapper = payload => {
    return {
        type : 'WORKFLOWS_RECEIVED',
        workflows : payload.workflows
    }
};


export const openSocketEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType('START_WEBSOCKET'),
    mergeMap( action => {
        const socket$ = getWebSocket();
        console.log(socket$);
        return socket$.pipe(            
            map(websocketMsgMapper),
            takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType('STOP_WEBSOCKET'))),
            catchError(error => of({ 
                    type : 'WORKFLOWS_RECEIVED_ERROR'
                }))
        );
    })
    );
```